# The safest way to abort an execution in a third-party library code

Tags: c#, .net, thread-abort

Here's a simplified version of a code in my solution that uses a pretty glitchy third-party library code:

```
public GlitchyThirdPartyComponent GetThirdPartyComponent(Stream stream)
{
    return new GlitchyThirdPartyComponent(stream);
}
```

For some streams the constructor of `GlitchyThirdPartyComponent` completely freaks out and starts consuming a lot of CPU power and memory and never quits until `OutOfMemoryException` occurs (smells like an infinite loop somewhere).

I'm trying to figure out the safest possible way to invoke `GetThirdPartyComponent` and then abort its execution after a certain timeout if it is still running.

I've examined a couple of possible solutions, but no solution seems to fit. There are a couple of reasons for it:

1. I have no access to third-party library source code. All assemblies are obfuscated, so no disassembling either
2. `GlitchyThirdPartyComponent` is not serializable, so no cross-appdomain or cross-process solutions
3. `GlitchyThirdPartyComponent` most likely uses COM (by the looks of its inteface), so `Thread.Abort` is a very unreliable option
4. While it's possible to use another third-party library or ask my current library vendor for a bugfix, these solutions require time, and my problem should be fixed ASAP

So, what should I do in this situation? Is `Thread.Abort` really the best solution here?

Comment: You've eliminated all the obvious solutions, there are just two left.  Use a telephone.  And delete the library when nobody picks up.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: @Padraic I'm using .NET 4.5.2

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap the call to `GlitchyThirdPartyComponent` in a `Task`. Then have a timeout. Something like this

```
int timeout = 1000;
var task = Task.Run(() => new GlitchyThirdPartyComponent(stream))
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task) {
    // task completed within timeout
} else { 
    // timeout logic
}
```

Comment: The OP already knows this is an option. The question is what to put in the `// timeout logic` part.